# Change in CSS left property not animating

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

In a list of steps in a recipe, all steps `divs` are displayed at `position: absolute` in a container with `overflow: hidden`.

A step hides off the right of the screen if it's an upcoming step, moves to the center (visible) for the current step, and then moves off to the left. (this is tracked as `currentness`) .

```js
export const CookingStep = ({ step, currentness }: Props) => {

  const StepWrapper = styled.div({
    width: '100%',
    background: 'lightgrey',
    height: '100px',
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    transition: '1s ease',
    left: currentness! * 100 + '%' // left = -1, center = 0, right = 1
  })

  return <StepWrapper children={ step.text }/>
}

/* REDUX CONTAINER */

const selectProps = (state: RootState, ownProps: Props) =>
  ({ currentness: getCurrentness(ownProps.step)(state) })

const CookingStepContainer = connect(selectProps)(CookingStep)

export default CookingStepContainer
```

Everything's working correctly **except it's not animating** (from the `transition` property).

I'm pretty damned sure I'm not rerendering the parent of the `CookingStep` when I change steps (which would cause the steps to be removed, not rerendered, or something like that, and prevent the animation).
I've tried a log statement inside of `StepsCarousel` to see when it renders, and it only renders once (at launch).

```js
// Wrappers are just styled components

const StepsCarousel = ({ steps, incStep, decStep }: Props) =>
  <CarouselWrapper>
    <Arrow onClick={ incStep }>{ "<" }</Arrow>
    <StepsWrapper>{
      steps.map((step, i) =>
        <CookingStepContainer step={ step } key={ i }/>
      )
    }</StepsWrapper>
    <Arrow onClick={ decStep }>{ ">" }</Arrow>
  </CarouselWrapper>
```

I've mocked up the whole html/css layout and animation behavior at https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-grass-hjkw9 which took me a silly amount of painstaking brainwracking hours but is animating perfectly. I can't see a difference between what I did there and what I did here.

(On the codesandbox I used classnames instead of directly setting the `left` property with a styled component. But I've actually tried using classnames in the app as well to no avail).

Why isn't the animation working?

Comment: Have you tried passing currentness to StepWrapper and then access it as `props => props.currentness` in the styled component

Comment: Oh of course! The styled component is being recreated on each render! I haven’t tried it yet but I will and I’m sure you’re right. Please write as an answer so I can give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Hey thanks man, check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `StyledWrapper` component out of `CookingStep` component and pass `currentness` as prop to `StyledWrapper`:

```
const StepWrapper = styled.div({
    width: '100%',
    background: 'lightgrey',
    height: '100px',
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    transition: '1s ease',
    left: ${props => props.currentness! * 100 + '%'}
  })

export const CookingStep = ({ step, currentness }: Props) => {
  return <StepWrapper currentness={currentness} children={ step.text }/>
}
```

Hope it helps :)